# cross browser Image allignment issues

Tags: html, css

My images are aligned perfectly when viewed on firefox but when I view them on chrome or internet explorer they re-arrange and float outside the container that I set up for them. I had set up a container to hold 20 thumb images.

I am new to coding and taking web design 1 so if anyone can, please help me. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS in your question.

Comment: In order to get help, please edit your question and add some source code representing your problem. For HTML/CSS issues, a good approach is to give a link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), especially if the code is too long for a question in SO.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a css reset. I like normalize.css http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/